# Ubuntu 10.04 - VM - Wireless card (wlan0)

Tags: wireless

Is there anyway to configure properly wifi card to my Ubuntu in VMa? Im choosing bridged connection to my WiFi Adapter but connection is only available when got checked box (cable connection).

After typing ifconfig i can see im connected to my router and it generates ip from DHCP.

But its eth0 instead of wlan0. After un-checking box with cable connection in VM its not working also eth0 is still visible without connection.

Regards,

Comment: Which hypervisor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Oracle VM VirtualBox** I afraid that you will have to have a USB wireless adapter to do so.

This is the only way I could expose my Wireless Adapter directly to the VM and here is why;

- VirtualBox -or any other type 2 hypervisor (type 2 is a virtualization application that is installed inside an Operating system like VirtualBox, VMWare Workstation.... Where type 1 is a baremetal hypervisor installed directly on the hardware, e.g.Xen Server, VM Ware ESX/ESXi.... Etc
- For type 2 hypervisors, when you add a virtual network interface. It actually creates a virtual interface inside the VM and Do Not expose your actual hardware to the VM.
- However, for USB devices -and speaking specifically on VirtualBox. It can map the device directly to the VM (this include USB wireless card, USB Drive, USB keyboard and mouse, USB WebCam....etc)

-please note that this option will make this USB device unusable for the host operating system.